# Need batch file to print the IPV4 Address, Subnet, Gateway and DNS Servers to a text file please

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I am trying to automate a task for work - we are currently doing screenshots of the ipconfig /all screen but all I need is the IPV4 Address, subnet, gateway ad DNS Servers.

I can get the IP address to print using the following:

```
echo IPAddress is: >> Admin.doc
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%
echo %ip% >> Admin.doc
```

I have several tasks that I need to automate and will be updating this document with each task.

Comment: The output file should be named .txt anf not .doc because it will be plain text. Save yourself (minor) issues!!

Comment: I am using .doc while testing as .txt seems to not work when I have the bat    file open for editing, and ultimately I am hoping to have screenshots of some things as well.

Comment: .doc is a proprietary file format and NOT plain text. What you are trying simply will not work.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %A in ('wmic nicconfig get ipaddress^,ipsubnet^,DNSHostname^,defaultipgateway /format:csv') do echo %A - %B - %C - %D - %E
```

or perhaps

```
for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=," %A in ('wmic nicconfig get ipaddress^,ipsubnet^,DNSHostname^,defaultipgateway /format:csv') do echo %A - %B - %C - %D
```

or

```
wmic nicconfig get ipaddress^,ipsubnet^,DNSHostname^,defaultipgateway /format:csv > File.txt
```

or

```
wmic /output:"file.txt" nicconfig get ipaddress^,ipsubnet^,DNSHostname^,defaultipgateway /format:csv
```

See `wmic /?`, `wmic /node /?`, `wmic /output /?`, `wmic /append /?`, `wmic nicconfig /?`, `wmic nicconfig get /?`, `wmic nicconfig call /?`, `wmic nicconfig set /?`, `wmic /format /?`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out - need to get the MAC id fixed though... its not pulling the MAC ID...

```
echo IPAddress is: >> Admin.doc
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%
echo %ip% >> Admin.doc



for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Subnet"') do set     sub=%%b
set sub=%sub:~1%
echo Subnet is: >> Admin.doc
echo %sub% >> Admin.doc


for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "Default"') do set gate=%%b
set gate=%gate:~1%
echo Gateway is: >> Admin.doc
echo %gate% >> Admin.doc



echo MAC ID is: >> Admin.doc
getmac >> Admin.doc
```

The mac is not necessary - but would be nice.

Comment: `ipconfig /all | findstr Physical` will return the MAC addresses for all the network connections. Your next task is to figure out which one you actually want ...

Comment: See my [su] answer [Is there a way to get only the Ethernet MAC address via command prompt in Windows?](http://superuser.com/a/892817)